# Which database support scalability and availability?

Tags: database, nosql

What database software can do these?

- Scalability via data partitioning, such as [consistent hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing).
- Redundancy for fail over.  Both memory cache and disk storage together.  Key-value data. Value is document type such as JSON.
- Prefers A and P in [CAP theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).

I heard that [MemcacheD](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiW2szOiIvMAhVJzWMKHQNiADkQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmemcached.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNE-sTYE_70SrRfg9z8bVDUw_u7Ldg&sig2=P5cWJa1obTUfogUeCKChdg&cad=rjt) can do these all, but I am not sure.

Here's details:

- Data storage volume is, <30KB JSON document for each key. Keys shall be >100,000,000.
- Data is accessed >10K times for a second.
- Persistence is needed for every key-value data.
- No need for transaction.
- Development environment is C#, but other languages are ok if the protocol spec is known.
- Map reduce is not needed.

Other considerations:

- it should be a standalone database (not an embedded one)
- As Consistency in CAP is less important, price matters. Cheaper is better, but free is not mandatory.